# GWT 2.x $entry function

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, jsni

Cannot find any developer information about this function. I just know that it's suggested to wrap JSNI JavaScript calls to Java methods with this `$entry` function. I found that it catches exceptions so Java code could handle them. Is it all it does?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to know exactly what happens, look into `com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry(JavaScriptObject jsFunction)`.

This function (at least in GWT 2.2.0) mainly calls `entry0(Object jsFunction, Object thisObj, Object arguments)`, which does the following:

- First, it flushes anything that has been scheduled by `Scheduler.scheduleEntry()`
- Then it makes sure to execute the jsFunction in a try block, to forward Exceptions to `GWT.getUncaughtExceptionHandler()`, if there is such a handler.
- Finally, it flushes anything that has been scheduled by `Scheduler.scheduleFinally()`